# @PreAuthorize annotation does not work for JpaRepository in Spring

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, repository

I have an issue with my UsersRepository as shown below.

I have a Users repo where i am trying to display all users in my db only if 
    the logged in user is an "Admin".

However, below code returns all users when i extend JpaRepository. When I extend CrudRepository it works fine.

Is this a known limitation or something i am doing wrong?

```
   @Repository
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    List<User> findById(List<Long> userIds);

    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);

    Boolean existsByUsername(String username);

}

   {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('test')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<User> findAll(Sort var1);


}
```

Adding the security config spring class to show security set up

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
     public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;


    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    private String[] permitted = new String[] {
            "/static/css/**","/static/media/**","/static/js/**", "/static/manifest.json"
    };

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    // this will create the auth manager that we will use to auth the user
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
               // .requiresChannel()
               // .anyRequest()
               // .requiresSecure()
               // .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(permitted)
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**", "/api/", "/")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll();
                //.authenticated();

        // Add our custom JWT security filter
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you tying to do @PreAuthorize on the RequestMapping not on Repository right ?

Comment: Yes, originally i removed the @RequestMApping line and just had it as such  for testing purposes:   @PreAuthorize("hasRole('test')")
    List<User> findAll(Sort var1);

Comment: Could you please specify Spring version

Comment: Spring version 2.1.2

Comment: Are you using springboot ?

Comment: Yes i am using spring boot. This works fine for CrudRepository but not for Jpa for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Can u show your implementation of security class? Did u mark it with the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` annotation?

Comment: Done, above. Kind regards